# How to properly cancel store filtering request

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs4

I have a combobox (extjs4.1.2) with the following configs:

```
  xtype:'combo',         
  store: 'MyItems',
  queryParam:'itemNumber',
  displayField:'itemNumber',
  hideTrigger:true,
  typeAhead:true,
  minChars:7,
  lastQuery: '',
  queryDelay:500
```

Everything works as expected and store fires a remote query on the 7th char. However if user keeps typing 8th character then another query is fired. The second query returns faster than the first, then first query returns and messes up the pull down. Is there a way to cancel the first query when a subsequent query is run ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended doing:

```
listeners:{
  beforequery:function(queryEvent){
    Ext.Ajax.abortAll(); //cancel any previous requests
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Ext.Ajax.abort()` or `Ext.Ajax.abortAll()` (ExtJS 4).
See the API Documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax

You can use it by intercepting the `onTypeAhead` function of the combo box:

```
comboObj.onTypeAhead = Ext.Function.createInterceptor(comboObj.onTypeAhead, function() {
    Ext.Ajax.abort(); //aborts the last Ajax request
    return true; //runs the onTypeAhead function
});
```

Or you could use the `autoAbort` property in `Ext.data.Connection` but there isn't much documentation on this. I'll try to get a working example for you on this.

Comment: this is not a very thorough answer to be useful.

Comment: thanks for the edits. I did it slightly different way. see my answer below.